# Trying to implement mouse movements to this basic javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove

I'm interested in converting my javascript code to a jquery code with mouse events. I have downloaded the latest version of jQuery and renamed it to "jquery.js" Then I modified my manifest .json file, the second code listed, to also include "jquery.js" Not completely sure if I added it correctly or not. Next I need to figure out how to put mouse events in the first code. Here is an example jQuery to activate the size selection that someone gave me as a tip:

```
$(".selectBox.exp-pdp-size-dropdown.exp-pdp-dropdown.selectBox-dropdown").focus().mousedown().mouseup();
```

I'm not sure exactly what to do so I would really appreciate some help or tips.

Summary of code purpose: Add specific size of shoe to cart on nike.com's new site that was updated at the beginning of August.

```
 var size_i_want = "12";

    function fRun()
    {
        // Select size option.
        var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];
        for(var i=0; i<sizesList.length; i++)
        {
            if(sizesList.options[i].text.trim() == size_i_want)
            {
                sizesList.selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }

        var aButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for(var i = 0; i < aButtons.length; ++i)
        {
            if(aButtons[i].className.indexOf("add-to-cart") > -1)
            {
                aButtons[i].click();
            }
        }
    }

    function fTick()
    {
        if(document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0] != undefined)
        {
            setTimeout("fRun()", 600);
            //fRun();
        }else{
            setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
        }
    }
    setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
```

Start manifest .json

```
{
    "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "name": "PreOrderHeat Bot Size 12",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "PreOrderHeat.Com",
    "icons": {
        "128": "Nike.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Nike bot"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*.nike.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "autobuy.js, jquery.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Don't take any more "tips" from that person.

Comment: Because that selector is ridiculous, there is no need for `focus()` and `.mousedown().mouseup()` should just be `click()`.

Comment: @Kingpin75801 I was being a smarty.  The advice you got may have been intended as a short summary of jQuery methods to research. Have you looked at the [jQuery documentation site](http://api.jquery.com) yet?

Comment: Okay, I think those are in there to make the movement more human-like. How do I implement that in the above code with movement into my code?

Comment: Please, I strongly sugest you at least read this http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/ before asking about jquery and this http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm before asking about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

@Rory - If you looked at the websites code you would see that there's no event handler for click() on the selector he's trying to invoke.. It uses a mousedown() to trigger then event handler.. click() does nothing. By chaining the focus() with the mousedown() doesn't hurt anything (granted it doesn't do anything either) but it allows you to see that the focus() works using that selector.

The OP is confusing two styles of scripting.. in the example he posted the method to select a size using the selectedIndex by setting that through the DOM. However he references the technique used to select size using the mouseevents.

Comment: I want to use mouseevents instead of using the selectedIndex